# Programmatically Deploying Bundle into OSGI Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I have a system setup where I am running Eclipse Equinox in a server-side application and in my Eclipse RCP Application. My goal is to take a plugin in the workspace and deploy it into the server-side app and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I know OSGI supports runtime bundle installs but would I have to compile my workspace project into a jar first? Is there an API I can use in Eclipse Runtime to say `..installBundle(String pathToJar or pathToProject)`?

Comment: See the javadoc of BundleContext.installBundle(location)

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the Javadoc, do you know how the location string works? Can I point to a non-compiled plugin project in my workspace to install or do I have to first build the plugin myself into a jar? I'm hoping I can do the install from source because I don't know how to build a plugin from my code.

Comment: You can specify the location in the same format as the _osgi.bundles_ setting in _eclipse/configuration/configuration.ini_ accepts. "reference:" on the beginning of the URL means that the content of the bundle will not be copied to the working directory of the OSGi container but it will be used from the location. Folders that contain classes and the resources can be specified in this way, too (only with reference: in the beginning).

Comment: Have a look at OSGi bundle development with [bndtools](http://bndtools.org). This is giving you immediate bundle creation during development time on every change/save. The created bundle can then be installed/updated inside your runtime via OSGi shell or Felix Webconsole.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I tested on eclipse equinox. If *"plugins"* is the name of the folder containing all your osgi bundles, a method to install and start a bundle from there is:

```
void installAndStartBundle(String bundlName) throws BundleException{
    BundleContext bundlecontext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
    Bundle b = bundlecontext.installBundle("file:plugins" + File.separator + bundleName);
    b.start();
}
```

where *bundleName* is the name with jar extension of the deployable bundle.

This is equivalent to the instructions from the osgi console

```
install file:plugins/<bundle name>.jar
start <bundle id>
```

In general, you might want to consider [Apache Felix File Install](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html) as a more robust option.